# How can I differentiate a parameter being None or being not present in Python?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python so sorry in advance if the answer to this is a basic concept.
I'm struggling with trying to identify when a parameter is None or is not received.

I wrote a quick example below to illustrate my doubt.

Considering I have the following Enum that I'll use as a datatype:

```
class Status(Enum):
    ACTIVE = "1"
    PENDING = "2"
    DELETED = "3"
```

I want to have a single function that can do 3 scenarios:

Build a dict with a field with a value:

```
{"name": "John", "status": "1"}
```

Build a dict with a field with null value:

```
{"name": "John", "status": None}
```

Build a dict without a field:

```
{"name": "John"}
```

For that, I created 3 tests:

```
def test_send_valid_status():
    request_body = build_request(name="John", status=Status.ACTIVE)
    assert body == {"name": "John", "status": "1"}

def test_send_null_status():
    request_body = build_request(name="John", status=None)
    assert body == {"name": "John", "status": None}

def test_dont_send_status():
    request_body = build_request(name="John")
    assert body == {"name": "John"}
```

**How can I write build_request() in order to pass the above scenarios?** Is important to me that the person calling `build_request()` knows there's a field `status` that can be sent and what datatype should be.

My first attempt was to make `status` optional:

```
def build_request(name: str, status: bool = None):
    request_body = {
        "name": name,
    }

    if status is not None:
        request_body["status"] = status.value

    return request_body
```

Of course this fails on `test_dont_send_status()` because `status` is assigned a `None` if I don't send the parameter.

My second attempt was to use kwargs and tell the user in the docs what to send:

```
def build_request(name: str, **kwargs):
    """
    :param name: str
    :param status: Status = None
    :return: dict
    """
    
    request_body = {
        "name": name,
    }
    
    for arg, value in kwargs.items():
        request_body[arg] = value.value

    return request_body
```

The problem here is that pycharm complains param status is not an argument. Also, it doesn't seem to be a robust solution.

How can I handle that difference between the parameter being None and the parameter not being sent?

Comment: If `None` is a valid input, then you have to choose a different sentinel value to indicate the lack of an argument.

Comment: @chepner do you mean creating a NoValue custom object to that end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you cannot differentiate. That's why using **kwargs is the right way.
Pycharm complaints because status indeed is not an argument of this function, it can take anything. Co you must do the type/value check manually (you cannot enforce the enum).

Another option is to use different default value than None, some constant would work. And then compare it to this constant.

```
NOT_PRESENT = []

def build_request(name: str, status: Union[bool, list] = NOT_PRESENT):
request_body = {
    "name": name,
}

if status is not NOT_PRESENT:
    request_body["status"] = status.value

return request_body
```

Comment: Nice solution, however you also should consider when status is None, as author specified (by now you will get exception trying to do `build_request("John", None)`, as None has no attribute 'value' , before checking `if status is not NOT_PRESENT`.

Comment: Thanks, the second option did the trick and adding @Grysik suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dictionary's get() method, which can take a value for the cases when the value is not found in the dict, the default is None here too but you can change it to something that makes sense and signals that the value was not found in the dict. You use it like this:

```
result = mydict.get(key_of_val_to_be_found, value_if_not_found)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a default value that you won't use.
For example:

```
def build_request(name: str, status="Empty"):
    request_body = { "name": name }
    
    if status == "Empty":
        pass
    elif status is None:
        request_body["status"] = None
    elif isinstance(status, bool):
        request_body["status"] = int(status)
    else:
        # manage invalid status here
        print("invalid status")

    return request_body
```